# Find string and replace it with HTML content in word document using c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I want to replace HTML content with string in word document. I've already add HTML content to the word document but I want to add HTML content replacing specific string in C# MVC.
Below is my code:

```
    public static void addhtmltodocx() //This function add HTML content end of the the word document
    {
        using (WordprocessingDocument myDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(@"C:\Users\1527858\Desktop\test.docx", true))
        {
            string html =
            @"<html>
                <head/>
                <body>
                    <b>Hello</b>
                </body>
            </html>";

            string altChunkId = "AltChunkId"+21;
            MainDocumentPart mainPart = myDoc.MainDocumentPart;
            AlternativeFormatImportPart chunk = mainPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart("application/xhtml+xml", altChunkId);

            using (Stream chunkStream = chunk.GetStream(FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            using (StreamWriter stringStream = new StreamWriter(chunkStream))
                stringStream.Write(html);

            AltChunk altChunk = new AltChunk();
            altChunk.Id = altChunkId;

            mainPart.Document.Body
                .InsertAfter(altChunk, mainPart.Document.Body.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph>().Last());
            
            mainPart.Document.Save();
        }
    }
```

Suppose below is my word file content:

```
test1
test2  // I want to replace test2 with the html content.
test3
```

Expected Output like:

test1
**Hello**
test3

> Find the string from word document and replace it with HTML data.

Could you help me with find string(test2) and replace it html content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the third party dll which is available in **Nuget package manager**. Here is the sample code solution. More Info : [VISIT](https://www.e-iceblue.com/forum/replace-text-with-html-content-t6895.html)

```
        string filename = @"C:\test.docx";
        Document document = new Document();
        document.LoadFromFile(filename);

        TextSelection[] selections1 = document.FindAllString("test2", true, true);
        //Here in first parameter you need pass the string which you want to replace.
        foreach (TextSelection selection1 in selections1)
        {
            TextRange range1 = selection1.GetAsOneRange();
            Paragraph paragraph = range1.OwnerParagraph;
            int index1 = paragraph.ChildObjects.IndexOf(range1);
            paragraph.AppendHTML("<b>Hello</b>");
            range1.OwnerParagraph.ChildObjects.Remove(range1);
        }
        document.SaveToFile(filename, FileFormat.Docx);
```

- Import below namespaces.

  ```
   using System.Drawing;
   using Spire.Doc;
   using Spire.Doc.Documents;
   using Spire.Doc.Fields;
   using Document = Spire.Doc.Document;
   using Paragraph = Spire.Doc.Documents.Paragraph;
  ```

For Implementation of this code please follow below step:
Step -1 : Open the **Nuget Package Manager**. 
Step -2 : Search **FreeSpire** in browse tab and install it.
Step -3 : Now add the above code. That's it Enjoy the Code.

Answer (score 0):

Sample code:

```
    // To search and replace content in a document part.
    public static void SearchAndReplace(string document)
    {
        using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(document, true))
        {
            string docText = null;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
            {
                docText = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }

            Regex regexText = new Regex("Hello world!");
            docText = regexText.Replace(docText, "Hi Everyone!");

            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
            {
                sw.Write(docText);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I had tried this code. Using this code if I find test2 then I replaced with _<b>hello</b>_ then the word file will get corrupted. This part of code is used to find and replace **simple string** in docx. I want to replace **HTML content** into word file. Could you please help me to add HTML content into word file with replacing test2? @juanma

Comment: not sure what you trying to achieve, but Words are XML not HTML. Just rename your word to .zip, open it and find the document.xml where your text is and you will see nodes. If you want to replace <html> <div> <b> tags just try to find them with RegEx like this: <(.*)>.*?|<(.*) /> and create a conditional to be sure there is a "html" "body" "div" or whatever you are looking for or you will mess your word because XML is also formated with < > tags.

Comment: I have already provided that part of code to add HTML content into word file. But in my code I have added HTML content in the last of the page but I want it in middle of the page. @juanma

Comment: add a tag {htmlcontent} in the middle of document find your html and replace the tag with the html.

Comment: I have tried to adding **{<b>Hello</b>}** in document.xml instead of test2 but file got corrupted. @Juanma

Comment: I have already provided the expected output in question.

Comment: html is encoded like this inside the XML: {&lt;b&gt;Hello&lt;/b&gt;} you cannot add < >